# Can we grant points based on outside reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, users

I just saw [a tweet](https://twitter.com/mediafinger/status/772887061791666176) which says:

> OH: "I can not answer questions on Erlang because I don't have enough
>   points on @StackOverflow " by @joeerl inventor of #Erlang

I understand that SO points are roughly "how much does SO trust you to make good content, based on past behavior" and not "how knowledgable are you, generally".

However, it seems like **a language creator should be given immediate clearance to answer questions, assuming their identity can be verified**.

Is there already a policy around this?

Comment: Answering questions requires no rep.... I don't see why he "can't answer". He just needs to create an account

Comment: I saw a similar story happening for Marshall Cline, the creator of the famous c++ FAQ.

Comment: I vaguely recall a Meta discussion, mentioning that in the early days of SO, someone was given immediate privileges. I think that user was Alan Kay, but I can't find the discussion back :-(

Comment: I don't think Dr. Kay was granted any arbitrary privileges. He just earned them by [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432922/significant-new-inventions-in-computing-since-1980) and [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357813/help-me-remember-a-quote-from-alan-kay/389642#389642) some questions.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more convinced I am that this statement was just a joke. (Maybe just a funny way of saying he doesn't have a Stack Overflow account.)

Comment: Well, I'm just waiting for someone to reply to that tweet... someone has a duty call... yeah

Comment: @Braiam I just replied. Sorry, everyone - my bad.

Comment: Stop trying to edit an answer into the question.  The question is where you ask the question, the answer is where you answer it.

Comment: It is merely a good excuse.  Add people like Bjarne Stroustrup, Herb Sutter, John Resig to that list of luminaries.  None of them lasted very long.  Well, you'd expect them to have something better to do than plow through questions from newbies :)

Comment: *Add people like Bjarne Stroustrup, Herb Sutter, John Resig to that list of luminaries. None of them lasted very long.* @HansPassant Did any of them say why or did they all just stop contributing at some point?

Comment: I didn't pay any real attention.  Nothing like a rage quit, afaik they just stopped showing up.  Bjarne and Herb's accounts got deleted due to inactivity.  John Resig posted two comments in January, he didn't sound terribly thrilled :)

Comment: @Servy Understood. I was really just trying to say "no need to waste your time reading and responding; my question was bunk." I'd vote to close instead, but "faulty premise" isn't one of the reasons I can choose.

Comment: [Herb's main account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter) wasn't deleted. Maybe he also posted some answers when he wasn't logged in, and that temporary account got deleted? Either way, no, the experts don't usually make a statement about why they've quit. There is no reasonable way to do that. These people are far too mature and civilized to come on Meta and leave a giant rant about why Stack Overflow sucks. You just realize that the site isn't for you, and you fade away and stop participating. It's something that we *should* worry about, though. It points to a real problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With just 1 reputation (which is where everybody starts, and you can't go below 1 reputation), you are able to [create posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts):

> #### What is asking and answering questions?
>
> The most basic privilege of all -- the right to ask a question, and the right to contribute an answer. This is generally available to everyone, regardless of reputation level.

So that tweet just isn't correct. Also, while Stack Overflow reputation does measure your expertise in certain languages/areas, it is *also* a measure of how well you know the site and its policies.

Comment: It is kind of misleading to say "once you reach 1 reputation", since *everyone* starts at 1 reputation and cannot fall below that threshold.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, I missed that. Thanks for noticing, I thought it was obvious but for new users it certainly isn't.

Comment: Technically the tweet could be correct, if they have not created an account yet, then they haven't managed to get that 1 rep point yet. :)

Answer (score 10):

You don't need any reputation to answer a question, unless that question is protected. In that case you need to have at least 10 reputation (the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/310998) doesn't count).

I don't think it's worth implementing a feature to allow someone with a verified identity to answer a protected question, because earning 9 reputation is very easy.

Comment: One would imagine it would be *especially* easy for someone who invented a language.